# Time interval in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

I use this Java code to generate timestamp with specific date mask:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSSS").format(new Date());
```

Howe I can generate second timestamp one month old than the previous?

I tried this:

```
String start_Date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+SSSS").format(new Date().getTime() - 900000000);
```

But I would like to get fixed month.

Comment: Please read my post first.

Comment: You should be using JDK 8 and the java.time package.

Comment: Correct. I use them.

Comment: You want to subtract one month from a date, the linked question shows you how to do that (the operation is adding 5 months in the linked question).

Comment: I don't see any java.time classes in your question.

Comment: I'm not aware how to implement this